# Get row number only for filtered rows in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataframe:

| id_cnt | id_prd | type | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | SS | 10 |
| 2 | A | AA | 20 |
| 3 | A | AA | 25 |
| 1 | B | AA | 55 |
| 2 | B | SS | 50 |
| 3 | B | AA | 75 |
| 4 | B | AA | 80 |

I need to add a new column: `rownumber`. For each `id_prd`, order by `price` and get row number, but only when `type = "AA"`.

Expected output:

| id_cnt | id_prd | type | price | rownumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | SS | 10 | null |
| 2 | A | AA | 20 | 2 |
| 3 | A | AA | 25 | 1 |
| 1 | B | AA | 55 | 3 |
| 2 | B | SS | 50 | null |
| 3 | B | AA | 75 | 2 |
| 4 | B | AA | 80 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Window` and partition by both `id_prd` and `type` and order by `price`, then get the `row_number` only for the case you have `type = AA`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, desc, col, lit, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [
    (1, "A", "SS", 10),
    (2, "A", "AA", 20),
    (3, "A", "AA", 25),
    (1, "B", "AA", 55),
    (2, "B", "SS", 50),
    (3, "B", "AA", 75),
    (4, "B", "AA", 80)]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id_cnt", "id_prd", "type", "price"])
            
window = Window.partitionBy("id_prd", "type").orderBy(desc("price"))

df.withColumn("row_number", when(col("type") == lit("AA"), row_number().over(window)).otherwise(None)).show()
```

```
+------+------+----+-----+----------+                                           
|id_cnt|id_prd|type|price|row_number|
+------+------+----+-----+----------+
|     3|     A|  AA|   25|         1|
|     2|     A|  AA|   20|         2|
|     1|     A|  SS|   10|      null|
|     4|     B|  AA|   80|         1|
|     3|     B|  AA|   75|         2|
|     1|     B|  AA|   55|         3|
|     2|     B|  SS|   50|      null|
+------+------+----+-----+----------+
```